# LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my gradle to latest version and now I am having this error.
`org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.`

I have seen other questions about this, but it didn't help. I have tried removing all the dependencies but the same error is shown, so it is not a compatibility issue?

[My gradle file](https://pastebin.com/36rDckL4)

Here's the full error: [link](https://pastebin.com/dGLY2C34)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version API you are using.

Solution 1: File => Invalidate Caches / Restart

Solution 2: Check the AndroidManifest.xml and build.gradle using same targetSdkVersion, minimum and maximum sdk version.

solution 3: Check dependencies in build.gradle file. Then comment out one by one and sync. For an example:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Comment: I have tried all of these, didn't help. I have created a new projest, copied my classes and it works now, but thanks.